# Pandas DataFrame - Replace NULL value of Datetime column with some old date

Tags: python, pandas

**Question**: How can we replace the `NULL` values of a `datetime` column in `Pandas DataFrame` to something like `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`?

I am using `Pandas` data frame to import a large data file into a `SQL Server 2019` table. My following code correctly replaces NULL values of numeric columns to 0, and NULL values of object (string) columns to empty string. But it does not change the NULL values of the datetime columns to `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`:

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

............
............
c = df.select_dtypes(np.datetime64).columns
df[c] = df[c].fillna('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Ref: [pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874276)

Comment: In the line `df[cols] = df[c].fillna('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')`, what is `cols`?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler That was a typo. I corrected that. Thank you for pointing it out early.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that 'fillna' doesn't pick up 'NULL' as this is a sql keyword for *NA values* - but not for pandas. Maybe try replacing directly that string in your code?

```
df[c].replace('NULL','1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```